# For a database, what number does it start with, 0, or 1?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, numbers

I am making a phpMyAdmin database for my website, and have something called "rank". I want there to be three ranks. For where it says "Length/Values" should I put 3 or 2? Is it like in Java where it starts with a 0 (i.e. an array of 3 is 0, 1, 2)?

And a follow up, if I put in 3, will it auto make it 0, 1, 2? Or is it 1, 2, 3?

Comment: You can put any value you want in a database.  Did you try to insert data?  Did you encounter a problem of some kind?

Comment: No, I just want to know from what number php starts with. 0 or 1?

Comment: PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are 0-indexed (meaning that they start at `0`).

Comment: Also, sorry about the "Length/Values" part of my question, I just realized that's unrelated.

Comment: Thank you FirstOne, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php is a Zero-based index language. You can find list of Zero-based & One-based index programming language [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array%5Fsystem%5Fcross-reference%5Flist)

Comment: Wikipedia is not _the best_ resource to lean on. Try using the official docs when possible. Ex, from the docs: [**arrays**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) _If no integer indices exist yet, the key will be 0 (zero)._

Comment: I am referring to the list of different language not the documentation. But thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind